# Unable to intregrate linkedin auth2.0 in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch the full profile link of Linked-In user in my Windows phone application. I have tried this code

```
  String _callbackUrl = "http://s-1-15-2-4033853409-3415519866-2771870237-856776843-3981727777-3206545648-3028839714";
  String _consumerKey = "75wtr84mz6uwed";
  String _scope = "r_fullprofile";
  String _authorizationCode;
  var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code"
                                + "&client_id=" + _consumerKey
                                + "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_scope)
                                + "&state=STATE"
                                + "&redirect_uri=" 
                                + Uri.EscapeDataString(_callbackUrl);
  // log(url);
  var startUri = new Uri(url);
  var endUri = new Uri(_callbackUrl);
  WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri);
```

But after calling `AuthenticateAndContinue` I see a blank screen, and after that it automatically reverts back to the application page

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn's servers won't be able to resolve that `_callbackUrl` value to send the authorization code back to you.

You need to use a static server value, that you have configured in your LinkedIn application's valid list of callback sources.  Unfortunately, there is no native SDK to facilitate authentication with LinkedIn on the Windows Phone platform at this time - only Android and iOS.